# Adding user to User Pool via Google Sign in not working

Tags: android, amazon-cognito

I am trying to add Google Sign In to my Android app.

I have changed the User Pool, added the Google Identity Provider, and it enabled it in App Client Step.

But when I sign in using Google Sign In in my app, it doesn't add the user to the Users and Groups.

I thought this was done automatically. What am I missing? What do I need to do for the user to show up?

I tried the Amplify documentation, but it doesn't explain how to do it.

https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/social_signin_web_ui/q/platform/android

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use Amplify to sign in instead. Still got to figure out some kinks, but it seems to work.

```
Amplify.Auth.signInWithSocialWebUI(
        AuthProvider.google(),
        this,
        result -> Log.i("AuthQuickstart", result.toString()),
        error -> Log.e("AuthQuickstart", error.toString())
);
```